# How to add values to channelData of message using hooks

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using the [Customization Plain UI sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/21.customization-plain-ui) and need to add custom data to the channelData. What is the best way to accomplish this when using this sample?

Comment: Instead of using hooks u can try back channel to add values to channelData.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a store middleware to the [Customization Plain UI](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/21.customization-plain-ui) sample that adds custom channel data by passing a custom store as a prop to the `Composer` component. For more details, take a look at the [Piggyback Data](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.a.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities) Web Chat Sample.

```js
export default () => {
  ...

  const store = useMemo(() => createStore({}, () => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
      action = simpleUpdateIn(
        action,
        ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'email'],
        () => 'johndoe@example.com'
      );
    }
     return next(action);
  }), []);

  ...

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      ...

      {!!directLine && (
        <Components.Composer directLine={directLine} store={store}>
          <PlainWebChat />
        </Components.Composer>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```